# Upload image with large size in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing an app that upload images by **laravel** and angular 2.
I changed in `php.ini` file as following:
`memory_limit = 128M`
`upload_max_filesize = 100M`
`max_file_uploads = 100`
But when I upload image that size is more than 10M it show this error

[image]

Could you show me the way to fix it?

Comment: Did you restart your web server? And if you use `php-fpm`, did you restart that?

Comment: yes, I restarted server with this command line /etc/init.d/httpd restart

Comment: increase the `post_max_size` in php.ini file

Comment: It run as well. Thank you very much @hassan